# JUnit/Jenkins like in cpp/Visual Studio

Tags: c++, testing, tdd

Consider you have a C++ project in Visual Studio
ANd you want to do Test Driven Developement

What is the best equivalent to java JUnit/Jenkins ?

Currently I think I'll use the tests tools included in Visual Studio and use a plugin of Jenkins

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Jenkins is not specific to Java; it can run tests/builds/etc. for any language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Jenkins QA Stack / Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271465/c-jenkins-qa-stack-tools)